# How to write a StateFlow in ViewModel instead of produceState in Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from the official sample [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/AdvancedStateAndSideEffectsCodelab).

I'm learning the Compose by the [article](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects#7) and the project.

I was told by the article the following content.

*We could map what the screen needs to display and the UiState in the ViewModel layer by using a stream of data, a StateFlow of type DetailsUiState, that the ViewModel updates when the information is ready and that Compose collects with the collectAsState() API that you already know about.*

Could you change Code A as StateFlow in ViewModel to do the same work?

**Code A**

```
data class DetailsUiState(
    val cityDetails: ExploreModel? = null,
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val throwError: Boolean = false
)

@Composable
fun DetailsScreen(
    onErrorLoading: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: DetailsViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val uiState by produceState(initialValue = DetailsUiState(isLoading = true)) {
        val cityDetailsResult = viewModel.cityDetails
        value = if (cityDetailsResult is Result.Success<ExploreModel>) {
            DetailsUiState(cityDetailsResult.data)
        } else {
            DetailsUiState(throwError = true)
        }
    }

    when {
        uiState.cityDetails != null -> {
            DetailsContent(uiState.cityDetails!!, modifier.fillMaxSize())
        }
        uiState.isLoading -> {
           ...
        }
        else -> { onErrorLoading() }
    }
}



@HiltViewModel
class DetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val destinationsRepository: DestinationsRepository,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    private val cityName = savedStateHandle.get<String>(KEY_ARG_DETAILS_CITY_NAME)!!

    val cityDetails: Result<ExploreModel>
        get() {
            val destination = destinationsRepository.getDestination(cityName)
            return if (destination != null) {
                Result.Success(destination)
            } else {
                Result.Error(IllegalArgumentException("City doesn't exist"))
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

produceState is nothing different other than wrapper that uses `LaunchedEffect` that stores initial state which is composed when Composable at composition then each time result returns from `ProduceStateScopeImpl` using coroutines.

```
@Composable
fun <T> produceState(
    initialValue: T,
    @BuilderInference producer: suspend ProduceStateScope<T>.() -> Unit
): State<T> {
    val result = remember { mutableStateOf(initialValue) }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        ProduceStateScopeImpl(result, coroutineContext).producer()
    }
    return result
}
```

So you can replace this with anything that has `val result = remember { mutableStateOf(initialValue) }` and updates this result like in a ViewModel or Image loading states in another Composable. You can change it as in your code and effects will be same.

Answer (score 1):

Hey here is my answer to your question

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DetailsScreen(
    onErrorLoading: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: DetailsViewModel
) {
    val cityDetails by viewModel.cityDetails.collectAsState()
    val error by viewModel.error.collectAsState()
    val isLoading by viewModel.isLoading.collectAsState()

    // Retrieve cityDetails on first composition
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.getCityDetails()
    }

    // If is loading, do whatever you want
    if (isLoading) {
        ...
    }

    // Check is there is an error
    error
        ?.let {
            onErrorLoading()
        }
        // If there is no error check if you have some cityDetails
        ?: cityDetails?.let {
            // if you have some cityDetails draw composable
            DetailsContent(it, modifier.fillMaxSize())
        }
}


@HiltViewModel
class DetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val destinationsRepository: DestinationsRepository,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    private val cityName = savedStateHandle.get<String>(KEY_ARG_DETAILS_CITY_NAME)!!
    val cityDetails = MutableStateFlow<ExploreModel?>(null)
    val error = MutableStateFlow<Throwable?>(null)
    val isLoading = MutableStateFlow(false)

    fun getCityDetails() = viewModelScope.launch {
        isLoading.emit(true)

        val destination = destinationsRepository.getDestination(cityName)
        if (destination != null) {
            cityDetails.emit(destination)
        } else {
            error.emit(IllegalArgumentException("City doesn't exist"))
        }

        isLoading.emit(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but I think your code will cause unnecessary recompose.